# Programmatically get the product name from $order

Tags: 7, ubercart

I need to get the product name using the `$order` variable in Ubercart. How can I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In ubercart **uc_products** table stores the product details. You can get product id from the $orders array and can fetch the required product data from
uc_products table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM uc_products WHERE nid = ". $pid;
```

Refer the links for more details
https://www.drupal.org/node/1940926

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this but I have to get product order details only based on order variable **$order**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link that you have to check [uc_order_get_product_list](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart%21uc_order%21uc_order.module/function/uc_order_get_product_list/7). ubecart API will help you alot:

you will get an array with the products when you pass the `$order` variable to it.

```
$product_list = uc_order_get_product_list($order)
```

check the `$product_list` variable and you'll find the product name/ node ids there.

if it's only node ids [node_load] method in Drupal will help you to get the product title. (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7.x)

work with [devel] (https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and development will be easier for you in drupal. use `dsm ($variable)` to display the variable content. it works like `var_dump($variable)` in PHP but has a more developer friendly interface for drupal.